# router failed to solve tabs

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-router-flux

在使用react-native-router-flux的时候，遇到一个问题：我从home页面跳转到me页面，用的Actions.replace(“me”)。
报错，“There is route defined for key undefined.Must be one of ‘square’,‘collection’,‘contact’,‘me’”。
我把me改成square是可以执行的，怎么解决呢？谢谢了！

My English is so bad!
I have a question when I use react-native-router-flux, I click a button (Actions.repalce(‘me’)) to go one page of tabs on home page ,but only the first page square is success, others failed, I need help!

```
<Router>
<Stack key="root">
    <Scene key="login" component={Login} title="Login"/>
    <Scene key="register" component={Register} title="Register"/>
    <Stack key="homeStack"><Scene key="home" component={Home} title="Home" hideNavbar/></Stack>
    <Scene key="tabs" tabs initial hideNavBar>
        <Scene key='square' component={Square} title="广场"/>
        <Scene key='collection' component={Collection} title="收藏"/>
        <Scene key='contact' component={Contact} title="联系人"/>
        <Scene key='me' component={Me} title="我"/>
    </Scene>
</Stack>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow. Your question is of very low quality. Would you mind describing how youre experiencing this problem?

Comment: @Webbanditten how about this?

Comment: @Tiw sorry, I’m newer to stack,and my english is so bad

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want to do but I would recommend you to try this react-native app template which already includes the react-native-navigation and redux state management: https://github.com/Cicko/react-native-app-skeleton